# Excluding a test based on device

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have noticed that there just isn't a way to make my tests viable on all possible devices, mainly because of Facebook login I mentioned [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764458/uiautomator-facebook-login)

That being said, is there a way to automatically skip a test based on device its running on? I know I can use @Suppress to skip it on every device, but is there a way to define when to skip?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the `AndroidJUnitRunner` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html) lists a few features that seem helpful to achieve what you have in mind. Namely, there are switches to only run tests with (`-e annotation`) or without (`-e notAnnotation`) a given annotation.

You could annotate some of your tests with `@OnlySamsung` and then -- depending on the device you run the test on -- include or exclude those using the described filter mechanism: `-e notAnnotation com.example.annotations.OnlySamsung`